# Sum until blank

Tags: excel, vba

I have 2 column, in column B, a list with blank in between, the numbers of text before blank can vary. I need to insert a sum of the range at the first line of text in column next to it. 
And my two attemps of vba works but then dosent work. 
Option 1: Works will insert "sum=" the range above with text.
Option 2: This inserts in the right place but only insert a "FALSE".

```
Example:
Column B:     ColumnC:
Header1       =SUM(B1:B4) eg. the sum of the range before first blank.
Sub1
Sub2
Sub3
"blank"
Header2       =SUM(B6:B8) eg. the sum of the range before first blank.
Sub1
Sub2
"blank"
```

```
Sub KSV_Option_1()
        Dim KSV_SrchRng As Range, cel As Range, KSV_Contain As String
        Set KSV_SrchRng = Range("B1:B99")
        For Each cel In KSV_SrchRng
            If InStr(cel.Value, "Forsikringspræmie") > 0 Then
                KSV_Contain = cel.Value
            ElseIf cel.Value <> "" Then
                    Dim xRg As Range
                    Dim i, j, StartRow, StartCol As Integer
                    Set xRg = Range("B1:B99")
                    StartRow = xRg.Row
                    StartCol = xRg.Column
                    For i = StartCol To xRg.Columns.Count + StartCol - 1
                        For j = xRg.Row To xRg.Rows.Count + StartRow - 1
                            If Cells(j, i) = "" Then
                                 Cells(j, i).Formula = "=SUM(" & Cells(StartRow, i).Address & ":" & Cells(j - 1, i).Address & ")"
                                StartRow = j + 1
                            End If
                        Next
                        StartRow = xRg.Row
                    Next
                End If
        Next cel
End Sub


Sub KSV_Option_2()
        Dim KSV_SrchRng As Range, cel As Range, KSV_Contain As String
        Set KSV_SrchRng = Range("B1:B99")
        For Each cel In KSV_SrchRng
            If InStr(cel.Value, "Forsikringspræmie") > 0 Then
                KSV_Contain = cel.Value
            ElseIf cel.Value <> "" Then
                    Dim xRg As Range
                    Dim i, j, StartRow, StartCol As Integer
                    Set xRg = Range("B1:B99")
                    StartRow = xRg.Row
                    StartCol = xRg.Column
                    For i = StartCol To xRg.Columns.Count + StartCol - 1
                        For j = xRg.Row To xRg.Rows.Count + StartRow - 1
                            If Cells(j, i) = "" Then
                                 cel.Offset(0, 1).Value = Cells(j, i).Formula = "=SUM(" & Cells(StartRow, i).Address & ":" & Cells(j - 1, i).Address & ")"
                                StartRow = j + 1
                            End If
                        Next
                        StartRow = xRg.Row
                    Next
                End If
        Next cel
End Sub
```

Comment: Please clarify, based on your statement "numbers of text before blank", are you trying sum values or count text in the column?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying sum the values in multiple ranges separated by a blank cell in "Col B". If I am right, here is a simple code that will sum the values in multiple ranges in a "Col B" that are separated by a blank cell. The Sum formula will be inserted into "Col C" to the right of the first cell in each sumRng. Change the sheet name as required.

```
For Each sumRng In Sheets("Sheet1").Columns("B").SpecialCells(xlConstants, xlNumbers).Areas
    sumA = sumRng.Address(False, False)
    sumRng.Offset(, 1).Resize(1, 1).Formula = "=SUM(" & sumA & ")"
Next sumRng
```

If you are just trying to count the number of cells that are in the range you can use this simple code. If you are counting the cells with numbers use `xlNumbers`, if you are counting cells with text use `xlConstants`.

```
For Each cntRng In Sheets("Sheet1").Columns("B").SpecialCells(xlConstants, xlNumbers).Areas
    cntA = cntRng.Address(False, False)
    cntRng.Offset(, 1).Resize(1, 1) = cntRng.Count
Next cntRng
```